# Oracle Partition pruning not happening

Tags: oracle

I have a fact table with millions of records. The table is range partitioned on a date column.

```
FACT_AUM (ACCOUNT_ID VARCHAR2(30),MARKET_VALUE NUMBER(20,6), POSTING_DATE DATE);
```

I have another temp table

```
ACCOUNT_TMP (ACCOUNT_ID VARCHAR2(30), POSTING_DATE DATE);
```

When I run this query by hard coding the date I see partition pruning happens and the results come back quickly

```
SELECT A.ACCOUNT_ID, SUM(A.MARKET_VALUE) FROM 
FACT_AUM A JOIN ACCOUNT_TMP B ON A.ACCOUNT_ID = B.ACCOUNT_ID 
AND A.POSTING_DATE=TO_DATE('30-DEC-2016',DD-MON-YYYY') GROUP BY 
A.ACCOUNT_ID;
```

when I run the following, I don't see partition pruning and the query keeps spinning

```
SELECT A.ACCOUNT_ID, SUM(A.MARKET_VALUE) FROM 
FACT_AUM A JOIN ACCOUNT_TMP B ON A.ACCOUNT_ID = B.ACCOUNT_ID 
AND A.POSTING_DATE = B.POSTING_DATE GROUP BY 
A.ACCOUNT_ID;
```

Any insights on this would be helpful.

Comment: I m not sure if I can share the DDL in this forum. I'll see if I can get a abridged version and post the relevant sections on the DDL

Comment: Execution plan of these two queries would be better to investigate further.

Comment: I checked the execution plan for both the queries. The one with hard coded date has the posting_date in the filter predicate and partition_start & partition_stop has a specific partition id. But the one with the join operation has the partition_start as 1 and partition_end as 146 (as the table has 146 partitions)

Comment: `CREATE TABLE FACT_AUM
(
 SK_PRODUCT NUMBER, 
 ACCOUNT_NUMBER VARCHAR2(30),
 CURRENCY_CODE VARCHAR2(5),
 TOTAL_SHARES NUMBER,
 NAV NUMBER,
 .....
 ....
)`

Comment: `PARTITION BY RANGE ("POSTING_DT") 
PARTITION "PART_JAN_2010"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2010-02-01 21:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
PARTITION "PART_FEB_2010"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2010-03-01 21:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) 
PARTITION "PART_MAR_2010"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2010-04-01 21:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) 
....
....
PARTITION "PART_DEC_2016"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2017-01-01 21:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))`

Comment: Do you think this snippet would help?

Comment: In your first query the optimizer knows the value of `POSTING_DATE` during hard parsing. So it can decide which partition to access to retrieve required rows. But in your second query optimizer doesn't know about this. You are getting `POSTING_DATE` from lots of partitions. Edit your question to add execution plan and these code snippets.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So the optimizer doesn't know the partitions until the query is executed. Is there a way to change the query to use the partitions. I was thinking of using a dynamic SQL to pick up the dates and use a function to populate the dates as CSV. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @sk411You are not providing any filter predicates in you second query (unlike your first one), which is why we have to scan all the partitions.

Comment: @sk411Moreover, why are you joining to this table anyway? There is no need. In fact, if you were to run this in 12c, join elimination would take place. Join elimination does not happen in earlier versions on multi-column joins.

Comment: Thanks BobC. I m running this query in Oracle 12c. FACT_AUM table has details on all account and their positions. The temp table gets populated with a set of accounts and dates.  I m joining these tables to match on the account numbers and the posting_dates. How can I add filter predicates in my 2nd Query. The temp table could have any number of accounts / posting_dates

Answer (score 0):

Oracle used partition pruning while you hard coded the value, because Oracle felt it would get benefit of doing the partition pruning there.

When you joined the fact table with your temporary ( i would reword it to staging) table, Oracle wouldn't be able to guess which all partitions would it have to hit for computing the answer. Please note Oracle will assess what would be the range of values available in the staging table.

But unless you provide stats of the tables involved, i couldn't dwell into more important topics of the table ordering and tables joins. For quick fix use an Order hint or nested loop hint.